# How to create a dashed line with arrows on each dash in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How to make a line from arrows like a dashed line but somewhat like this "> > > >" for direction of the flow. I am trying to connect nodes via lines but my nodes have to resizable rectangles and it hides the arrowheads , which is why I am looking for such arrow(ed) line. Specifying arrow in the middle could also solve the problem but attr("marker-middle", "url(#arrowhead)") does not work in my code.

Here's the relevant code

```
svg
    .append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attrs({
      id: "arrowhead",
      viewBox: "-0 -5 10 10",
      refX: 13,
      refY: 0,
      orient: "auto",
      markerWidth: 3,
      markerHeight: 3
    })
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .call(
      d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        console.log(d3.event.transform);
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
      })
    );


var link = svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("line_class.line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.max(
        ((d.thickness - min_thickness) /
          (max_thickness - min_thickness + 0.01)) *
          5,
        3
      );
    })
    .style("stroke", "pink")
    .text("text", function(d) {
      return d.linkname;
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.9);
      div
        .html("Name: " + d.linkname)
        .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px")
        .style("width", "auto")
        .style("height", "auto");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });


link.call(updateState1);


function updateState1() {
link 

      .each(function(d) {
//d3.select(this).attr("marker-mid", "url(#arrowhead)");
d3.select(this).attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");

      });
  }
```

Comment: can you add a working snippet, that would help addressing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var config = [];

var graph = {
  nodes: [
    { name: "A" },
    { name: "B" },
    { name: "C" },
    { name: "D" },
    { name: "Dummy1" },
    { name: "Dummy2" },
    { name: "Dummy3" },
    { name: "Dummy4" }
  ],

  links: [
    { source: "A", target: "B", linkname: "A0" },
    { source: "A", target: "C", linkname: "A0" },
    { source: "A", target: "D", linkname: "A1" },
    { source: "Dummy1", target: "A", linkname: "input" },
    { source: "B", target: "Dummy2", linkname: "B" },
    { source: "C", target: "Dummy3", linkname: "C" },
    { source: "D", target: "Dummy4", linkname: "D" }
  ]
};

var optArray = [];
labelAnchors = [];
labelAnchorLinks = [];

highlightNode_button = d3.select("#highlightNode");
highlightNode_button.on("click", highlightNode);

shrinkNode_button = d3.select("#shrinkNode");
shrinkNode_button.on("click", minimizeNode);

for (var i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length - 1; i++) {
  optArray.push(graph.nodes[i].name);
}

optArray = optArray.sort();

$(function() {
  $("#targetNode").autocomplete({
    source: optArray
  });
});

//used to find max thickness of all the nodes, which is used for normalizing later on.
var max_thickness = d3.max(graph.links, function(d) {
  return d.thickness;
});

//used to find min thickness of all the nodes, which is used for normalizing later on.
var min_thickness = d3.min(graph.links, function(d) {
  return d.thickness;
});

var svg1 = d3.select("svg");
var width = +screen.width;
var height = +screen.height - 500;

svg1.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

var svg = svg1
  // .call(
  //   zoom.on("zoom", function() {
  //     svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  //   })
  // )
  .call(zoom)
  .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
  .append("g");
// Defining the gradient
//used for coloring the nodes

var gradient = svg

  .append("svg:defs")
  .append("svg:linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "gradient")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y2", "100%")

  .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

// Define the gradient colors
gradient
  .append("svg:stop")
  .attr("offset", "0%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#b721ff")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient
  .append("svg:stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", "#21d4fd")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var linkText = svg
  .selectAll(".gLink")
  .data(graph.links)
  .append("text")
  .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    if (d.target.x > d.source.x) {
      return d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2;
    } else {
      return d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x) / 2;
    }
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    if (d.target.y > d.source.y) {
      return d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2;
    } else {
      return d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y) / 2;
    }
  })
  .attr("fill", "Black")
  .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.linkname;
  });

var dragDrop = d3
  .drag()
  .on("start", node => {
    node.fx = node.x;
    node.fy = node.y;
  })
  .on("drag", node => {
    simulation.alphaTarget(1).restart();
    node.fx = d3.event.x;
    node.fy = d3.event.y;
  })
  .on("end", node => {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
      simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    }
    node.fx = null;
    node.fy = null;
  });

var linkForce = d3
  .forceLink(graph.links)
  .id(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .distance(50);
//.strength(0.5) to specify the pulling strength from each link
// strength from each node

// Saving a reference to node attribute
var nodeForce = d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30);

var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
  .force("links", linkForce)
  .force("charge", nodeForce)
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .on("tick", ticked);

var div = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

svg
  .append("defs")
  .append("marker")
  .attrs({
    id: "arrowhead",
    viewBox: "-0 -5 10 10",
    refX: 100,
    refY: 0,
    orient: "auto-start-reverse",
    markerWidth: 3,
    markerHeight: 3
  })
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5")
  .attr("fill", "black");
{
  {
    /* .call(
      d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        console.log(d3.event.transform);
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
      })
    ); */
  }
}

var link = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("line_class.line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
    return Math.max(
      ((d.thickness - min_thickness) / (max_thickness - min_thickness + 0.01)) *
        5,
      3
    );
  })
  .style("stroke", "pink")
  .text("text", function(d) {
    return d.linkname;
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0.9);
    div
      .html("Name: " + d.linkname)
      .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
      .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px")
      .style("width", "auto")
      .style("height", "auto");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })
  .attr("marker-start", "url(#arrowhead)");
// .attr("marker-start", "url(#arrowhead)")
// .attr("marker-mid", "url(#arrowhead)")
// .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");

// var line = link

var edgepaths = svg
  .selectAll(".edgepath")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return (
      "M " +
      d.source.x +
      " " +
      d.source.y +
      " L " +
      d.target.x +
      " " +
      d.target.y
    );
  })
  .attr("class", "edgepath")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "edgepath" + i;
  })
  .style("pointer-events", "none");

var radius = 4;
var node_data_array = [];
var node_name = "";

var node = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("circle_class.circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)")
  .style("transform", "translate(-20px,-10px)")
  .attr("stroke", "purple")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    node_name = d.name;
    return d.name;
  })
  .on("dblclick", connectedNodes);

var textElements_nodes = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .attr("font-size", 15)
  .attr("dx", 15)
  .attr("dy", -5);

node.call(dragDrop);

link.call(updateState1);

var path = document.querySelector("path"),
  totalLength = path.getTotalLength(),
  group = totalLength / 20,
  start;

var arrowheads = d3
  .select("svg")
  .selectAll("use")
  .data(
    d3.range(20).map(function(d) {
      return d * group + 50;
    })
  )
  .enter()
  .append("use")
  .attr("xlink:href", "#arrowhead");

path.style.strokeDasharray = "50," + (group - 50);

requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update(t) {
  if (!start) {
    start = t;
  }

  var offset = (-group * ((t - start) % 900)) / 900;

  path.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;

  arrowheads.attr("transform", function(d) {
    var l = d - offset;

    if (l < 0) {
      l = totalLength + l;
    } else if (l > totalLength) {
      l -= totalLength;
    }

    var p = pointAtLength(l);
    return "translate(" + p + ") rotate( " + angleAtLength(l) + ")";
  });

  //requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function pointAtLength(l) {
  var xy = path.getPointAtLength(l);
  return [xy.x, xy.y];
}

// Approximate tangent
function angleAtLength(l) {
  var a = pointAtLength(Math.max(l - 0.01, 0)), // this could be slightly negative
    b = pointAtLength(l + 0.01); // browsers cap at total length

  return (Math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0]) * 180) / Math.PI;
}

// link.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
function updateState1() {
  link.each(function(d) {
    var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    var num = 0;
    if (d.source.name.startsWith("Dummy")) {
      num = 1;
      console.log("Inside 1");
      console.log(
        "Source is ",
        d.source.name,
        " and target is ",
        d.target.name
      );
    } else if (d.target.name.startsWith("Dummy")) {
      num = 2;
      console.log("Inside 2");
      console.log(
        "Source is ",
        d.source.name,
        " and target is ",
        d.target.name
      );
    } else {
      num = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < graph.input_nodes.length; i++) {
        if (graph.input_nodes[i].name == d.source.name) {
          num = 1;
        }
      }
    }

    d3.select(this).style("stroke", function(d) {
      return colors[num];
    });

    {
      {
        /* d3.select(this).attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)"); */
      }
    }
    {
      {
        /* d3.select(this).attr("marker-mid", "url(#arrowhead)"); */
      }
    }
    // .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");
  });
}

function pointOnRect(x, y, minX, minY, maxX, maxY, validate) {
  //assert minX <= maxX;
  //assert minY <= maxY;
  if (validate && minX < x && x < maxX && minY < y && y < maxY)
    throw "Point " +
      [x, y] +
      "cannot be inside " +
      "the rectangle: " +
      [minX, minY] +
      " - " +
      [maxX, maxY] +
      ".";
  var midX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
  var midY = (minY + maxY) / 2;
  // if (midX - x == 0) -> m == ±Inf -> minYx/maxYx == x (because value / ±Inf = ±0)
  var m = (midY - y) / (midX - x);

  if (x <= midX) {
    // check "left" side
    var minXy = m * (minX - x) + y;
    if (minY <= minXy && minXy <= maxY) return { x: minX, y: minXy };
  }

  if (x >= midX) {
    // check "right" side
    var maxXy = m * (maxX - x) + y;
    if (minY <= maxXy && maxXy <= maxY) return { x: maxX, y: maxXy };
  }

  if (y <= midY) {
    // check "top" side
    var minYx = (minY - y) / m + x;
    if (minX <= minYx && minYx <= maxX) return { x: minYx, y: minY };
  }

  if (y >= midY) {
    // check "bottom" side
    var maxYx = (maxY - y) / m + x;
    if (minX <= maxYx && maxYx <= maxX) return { x: maxYx, y: maxY };
  }

  // edge case when finding midpoint intersection: m = 0/0 = NaN
  if (x === midX && y === midY) return { x: x, y: y };

  // Should never happen :) If it does, please tell me!
  throw "Cannot find intersection for " +
    [x, y] +
    " inside rectangle " +
    [minX, minY] +
    " - " +
    [maxX, maxY] +
    ".";
}

var label_toggle = 0;
function show_hide_node_labels() {
  if (label_toggle) {
    textElements_nodes.style("visibility", "visible");
  } else {
    textElements_nodes.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
  label_toggle = !label_toggle;
}

var toggle = 0;

var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
  linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
}
graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
  linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

//DAT GUI for controls
var gui = new dat.GUI({ width: 300 });

config = {
  linkStrength: 1,
  linkDistance: 180,
  nodeStrength: -30,
  Width: 40,
  Height: 20,
  restart: reset,
  showHideNodeLabels: show_hide_node_labels
};

var linkDistanceChanger = gui
  .add(config, "linkDistance", 0, 400)
  .step(1)
  .name("Link Distance");
linkDistanceChanger.onChange(function(value) {
  linkForce.distance(value);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
});

var linkStrengthChanger = gui
  .add(config, "linkStrength", 0, 1)
  .name("Link Strength");
linkStrengthChanger.onChange(function(value) {
  linkForce.strength(value);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
});

var nodeStrengthChanger = gui
  .add(config, "nodeStrength", -500, -1)
  .step(1)
  .name("Node Strength");
nodeStrengthChanger.onChange(function(value) {
  nodeForce.strength(value);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
});

var widthChanger = gui
  .add(config, "Width", 4, 100)
  .step(1)
  .name("Node Width");
widthChanger.onChange(function(value) {
  node.attr("width", value);
  og_width = value;
  // d3.select("#arrowhead").attrs({
  //   markerWidth: value * 0.4,
  //   markerHeight: value * 0.4
  // });
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
});

var heightChanger = gui
  .add(config, "Height", 2, 80)
  .step(1)
  .name("Node Height");
heightChanger.onChange(function(value) {
  node.attr("height", value);
  og_height = value;
  // d3.select("#arrowhead").attrs({
  //   markerWidth: value * 0.4,
  //   markerHeight: value * 0.4
  // });
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
});

gui.add(config, "showHideNodeLabels").name("Show/Hide Node Labels");

gui.add(config, "restart").name("Restart");

for (i = 0; i < gui.__ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
  gui.__ul.childNodes[i].classList += " longtext";
}

function reset() {
  window.location.reload();
}

//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
function neighboring(a, b) {
  return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}

function connectedNodes() {
  if (toggle == 0) {
    //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
    d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
    node.style("opacity", function(o) {
      return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
    });

    link.style("opacity", function(o) {
      return (d.index == o.source.index) | (d.index == o.target.index)
        ? 1
        : 0.1;
    });

    textElements_nodes.style("opacity", function(o) {
      return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
    });

    toggle = 1;
  } else {
    //Put them back to opacity=1
    node.style("opacity", 1);
    link.style("opacity", 1);
    textElements_nodes.style("opacity", 1);
    toggle = 0;
  }
}

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var inter = pointOnRect(
        d.source.x,
        d.source.y,
        d.target.x - 20,
        d.target.y - 20,
        d.target.x + 40 - 20,
        d.target.y + 20 - 20
      );

      return (
        "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + inter.x + "," + inter.y
      );
    });

  node
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  textElements_nodes.attr("x", node => node.x).attr("y", node => node.y);

  edgepaths.attr("d", function(d) {
    var path =
      "M " +
      d.source.x +
      " " +
      d.source.y +
      " L " +
      d.target.x +
      " " +
      d.target.y;
    return path;
  });

  var ticking = false;
}

var pulse = false;

function pulsed(rect) {
  (function repeat() {
    if (pulse) {
      rect
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .attr("width", config.Width)
        .attr("height", config.Height)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("width", config.Width * 3)
        .attr("height", config.Height * 3)
        .transition()
        .duration(400)
        .attr("stroke-width", 65)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .attr("width", config.Width)
        .attr("height", config.Height)
        .ease(d3.easeSin)
        .on("end", repeat);
    } else {
      ticking = false;
      rect
        .attr("width", config.Width)
        .attr("height", config.Height)
        .attr("fill", "url(#gradient)")
        .attr("stroke", "purple");
    }
  })();
}

function highlightNode() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("targetNode");
  var temp = userInput.value;
  var userInputRefined = temp.replace(/[/]/g, "\\/");
  // make userInput work with "/" as they are considered special characters
  // the char "/" is escaped with escape characters.
  theNode = d3.select("#" + userInputRefined);
  const isEmpty = theNode.empty();
  if (isEmpty) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Given node doesn't exist";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  }
  pulse = true;
  if (pulse) {
    pulsed(theNode);
  }

  scalingFactor = 0.5;
  // Create a zoom transform from d3.zoomIdentity
  var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(
      screen.width / 2 - scalingFactor * theNode.attr("x"),
      screen.height / 4 - scalingFactor * theNode.attr("y")
    )
    .scale(scalingFactor);
  // Apply the zoom and trigger a zoom event:
  svg1.call(zoom.transform, transform);
}

function minimizeNode() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("targetNode");
  var temp = userInput.value;
  var userInputRefined = temp.replace(/[/]/g, "\\/");
  // make userInput work with "/" as they are considered special characters
  // the char "/" is escaped with escape characters.
  theNode = d3.select("#" + userInputRefined);
  const isEmpty = theNode.empty();
  if (isEmpty) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Given node doesn't exist";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  }
  pulse = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=" />
    <title>Force Layout Example 9</title>
    <style>
      div.tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 60px;
        height: 28px;
        padding: 2px;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        background: lightsteelblue;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        pointer-events: none;
      }

      .longtext {
        line-height: 13px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 120%;
      }

      rect.zoom-panel {
        cursor: move;
        fill: #fff;
        pointer-events: all;
      }
      
      .bar {
        fill: rgb(70, 180, 70);
      }

      .graph-svg-component {
        background-color: green;
      }

      path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #d3008c;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }

      #arrowhead {
        fill: #d3008c;
        stroke: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg></svg>

    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-drag.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-transition.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.6/dat.gui.min.js"
    ></script>

    <link
      href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

I think this is what you want, this code snippet based on this [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/veltman/f1172731aa3c01fb5179536f9dea0a58) snippet and it meant to be animated by I removed the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) call from the update function.

regarding your original issue with nodes hiding the arrow, you can use [refX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/refX) and [refY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/refY) attribute on `<marker>` to change its offset.

```js
var path = document.querySelector("path"),
    totalLength = path.getTotalLength(),
    group = totalLength / 20,
    start;

var arrowheads = d3.select("svg").selectAll("use")
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function(d){ return d * group + 50; }))
  .enter()
  .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#arrowhead");

path.style.strokeDasharray = "50," + (group - 50);

requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update(t) {
  if (!start) {
    start = t;
  }

  var offset = -group * ((t - start) % 900) / 900;

  path.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;

  arrowheads.attr("transform",function(d){

    var l = d - offset;

    if (l < 0) {
      l = totalLength + l;
    } else if (l > totalLength) {
      l -= totalLength;
    }

    var p = pointAtLength(l);
    return "translate(" + p + ") rotate( " + angleAtLength(l) + ")";
  });

  //requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function pointAtLength(l) {

  var xy = path.getPointAtLength(l);
  return [xy.x, xy.y];

}

// Approximate tangent
function angleAtLength(l) {

  var a = pointAtLength(Math.max(l - 0.01,0)), // this could be slightly negative
      b = pointAtLength(l + 0.01); // browsers cap at total length

  return Math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0]) * 180 / Math.PI;

}
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #d3008c;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#arrowhead {
  fill: #d3008c;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960" height="500">
  <path d="M636.5,315c-0.4-18.7,1.9-27.9-5.3-35.9
   c-22.7-25-107.3-2.8-118.3,35.9c-7,24.4,20.6,37.2,16,71c-4,29.6-30.8,60.7-56.5,61.1c-30.8,0.4-32.9-43.8-81.7-70.2
   c-50.9-27.6-110.1-12.9-125.2-9.2c-66.1,16.4-82.2,56.9-109.2,47.3c-38-13.6-55.9-112.1-19.8-143.5c39-34,121.2,27.7,148.1-3.8
   c18-21.1,3.1-74.3-25.2-105.3c-31.1-34.1-70.1-32.4-105.3-76.3c-8.2-10.2-16.9-23.8-15.3-39.7c1.2-11.4,7.5-23.3,15.3-29
   c33.8-25,101.6,62.6,193.1,59.5c40.1-1.3,38.7-18.5,99.2-38.9c126.2-42.6,242.4-4.9,297.7,13c54.7,17.7,105.4,35,129.8,82.4
   c13,25.3,22.9,67.7,4.6,87c-11.6,12.3-25.1,5.1-46.6,20.6c-2.8,2-28.9,21.4-32.1,49.6c-3.1,27.4,18.7,35,29,70.2
   c8.8,30.1,8.5,77.8-18.3,99.2c-32.3,25.8-87,0.6-100-5.3c-69.6-32-67.2-88.4-73.3-109.2z"/>
    <defs>
      <path id="arrowhead" d="M7,0 L-7,-5 L-7,5 Z" />
    </defs>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you explicitly mentioning the path in html or is JS creating it for you? Because for my code it is created dynamically by D3. I don't know if that's the reason such arrows are not appearing in my case

Comment: In the snippet the path is hardcoded but, even if it is dynamic it should work by using `strokeDashoffset` you can specify the path dash length, then using D3 you can calculate its end point and append the arrow marker to it (in my snippet its in update function).

Comment: can you add a snippet, I might be able to work it out!

Comment: Added the snippet , it has a lot of unused code though.

Comment: Ok will check it now.

Comment: I updated the snippet that you added, can you check on your machine, not sure why its not running here! I added the arrow and changed its location through `refX` attribute.

Comment: The arrows still are continuous lines , could it be made dashed line with arrows as in the example.

Comment: Will check it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208268/discussion-between-mamoun-othman-and-amipro).